# How do i set a specific template for a specific module in drupal 6 using hook_theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

Is there any way by which i could assign a template to my custom module.I heard it may be possible.I tried out with the hook_theme function.My hook_theme looks something like this

```
    function special_theme() {
return array(
    'special' => array(
      'template' => 'special',
      'arguments' => array('link' => NULL),
    ),
  );
}
```

I do have a special.tpl.php file in my module folder.But the tpl file is  not called.Its my default template that is been shown as output.Could someone please help me in the right direction.would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you define via `hook_theme()` is an available template, not one that is automatically used. In order to use that template you need to call `theme('special', $link);`.

It is also advised to avoid using simple words for theme names to avoid collisions ( try `mymodule_special` instead ).

Also note (though basic), that you also need to `print` the return value of `theme()`, it does not get automatically printed. So for instance,

```
print theme('special', $link);
```

Comment: sorry to ask,where should i be calling this theme('special', $link);.

Comment: wherever you would want to output your `special` themed `$link` -- sorry for being cryptic but that is too general.

Comment: tanx.now the special.tpl.php page is called.I do had a  default.tpl.php file that i used as a default template.I find that now both of the tpl contents are being shown.I just made an echo in the special.tpl.php page ..The echoed text along with the contents of the default.tpl.php file is being shown.why is it that both the tpl file are shown..?